# How do I identify and remove curves I don't want?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Part of a project I am working on involves fitting a curve to each set of data and moving forward from there. Curves fit very nicely on some sets, but very poorly on others and bad fits can happen in many different ways. I need to identify bad fits and remove them from the dataset.

Here is an example where groups a and b are the curves I am looking for, but group c is the wrong shape and group d has one point that would be a major residual.

```
df4 <- data.frame(group = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
                            "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d"),
                  pop = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  value  = c(1,2,3,2.5,2,2,3,4,3.5,3,3,2,1,2,2.5,0.5,1.5,6,2,1.5))

ggplot(df4, aes(x = pop, y = value, color = group)) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula = y~poly(x,2), se = FALSE)+
  geom_point()
```

I have 25,000 sets of four like this.

Comment: You need to establish formal criteria for a "bad fit". This site is for coding errors, there's lots of resources online to establish goodness-of-fit metrics that you could apply to your models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the statistical perspective what @astrofunkswag said is correct. You have to define a statistical criteria in order to avoid the curves. Fortunately for us, that is possible using `broom` package that can replicate the functions in `geom_smooth()` and save in a dataframe all the required statistics in order to evaluate how good a model is. Here the code where I will show you how to make a kind of statistical filter. First the data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
#Data
df4 <- data.frame(group = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
                            "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d"),
                  pop = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  value  = c(1,2,3,2.5,2,2,3,4,3.5,3,3,2,1,2,2.5,0.5,1.5,6,2,1.5))
```

Now, we will replicate the model in `geom_smooth()` by group and save the different statistics in a new dataframe:

```
#Fit models by group
df5 <- df4 %>% group_by(group) %>%
  do(fitmod = glance(lm(value ~ poly(pop,2), data = .))) %>% 
  unnest(fitmod) %>% dplyr::select(group,r.squared)
```

In previous code, I only have selected `r.squared` but these are all the statistics from the fitted models:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 12
  group r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC deviance
  <fct>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <int>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1 a         0.942         0.883 0.254     16.1   0.0584     3  2.06   3.89  2.32    0.129
2 b         0.942         0.883 0.254     16.1   0.0584     3  2.06   3.89  2.32    0.129
3 c         0.857         0.714 0.396      6     0.143      3 -0.177  8.35  6.79    0.314
4 d         0.550         0.101 2.03       1.22  0.450      3 -8.34  24.7  23.1     8.23 
# ... with 1 more variable: df.residual <int>
```

You can define a criteria using any of those measures. In our case, I will use `r.squared` because it measures how good the fit is. This is the output in `df5`:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  group r.squared
  <fct>     <dbl>
1 a         0.942
2 b         0.942
3 c         0.857
4 d         0.550
```

As data analyst, I could set that models with good performance are those with a `r.squared` above 0.9. So with that definition I could build next pipeline using `left_join()` and `filter()` in order to keep only the models with proper fitting:

```
#Pipeline for plots
df4 %>% left_join(df5) %>%
  filter(r.squared>=0.9) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = pop, y = value, color = group)) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula = y~poly(x,2), se = FALSE)+
  geom_point()
```

The output:

[image]

You can use any statistical measure in order to define the models with good fitting and you could set up all the code in a function in order to apply to multiple dataframes.